# How to construct a Promise that calls an async function inside of it, parses the result, and then resolves/rejects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I would like to write a function `getUser()` that returns a Promise where upon `resolve` it delivers the user object and upon `reject` it delivers the error. I'm using axios to make the request.

Here's what I currently have.

```
async function getUser() {

    try {
        const userResponse = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: "some_url",
            data: "some string data",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        if (userResponse.data.status === 'success') {
            // resolve(validateResponse.data);
        } else {
            // reject(validateResponse.data);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // reject(validateResponse.data);
    }

}
```

I would like to wrap the entire `try...catch` block inside a `Promise` constructor, but the Promise constructor is `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})` and not `new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {...})`. I know I can do the latter but [it's an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor).

The `Promise` approach doesn't necessarily work either because when I use the `Promise` returned by `getUser()` and `.catch()` any errors, I won't know if the error came from the response from the server (the status was not `'success'`) or if the request itself failed.

What is the safest way to get around this problem? I know there is a brute force solution of just mimicking the `Promise` API without actually using it, or declaring an `async` Promise, but I feel like I'm encountering an anti-pattern every time.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm unconvinced you need to use the Promise API, but to be sure, what is, and where does  the `validateResponse` object  come from?

Comment: "*[It] doesn't necessarily work either because when I use the [promise] returned by  `getUser()` and catch any errors, I won't know if the error came from the response from the server or if the request itself failed.*" - uh, then what else do you want to do? The solution that `reject()`s in those two cases seems to be exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer this conceptually.

When you call an async function, it immediately returns a promise to the code-scope that called that function.

Inside of an async function, you don't need to use `resolve` and `reject`. Instead you can just use `return` and `throw`. What ever you `return` is what the promise will resolve to. If you `throw`, that's what the promise will "reject" to. Try something like this:

```
async function getUser() {

    try {
        const userResponse = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: "some_url",
            data: "some string data",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        if (userResponse.data.status === 'success') {
            return validateResponse.data;
        } else {
            throw new Error(validateResponse.data);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

After async/await came out, I stopped liking the `then` syntax when dealing with promises. To avoid `then`, call `getUser` from the body of an async function. If you're not calling `getUser` from the body of an async function, you won't be able to `await` what it resolves to; you'll have to use `then` instead. Or, you can wrap that calling code in an **immediately invoked async function** just so you can indeed uses `await`. Here's a rough example of how my code (that calls `getUser`) might look:

```
(async function()
{
    let user = await getUser();
    if(!user)
    {
        console.error(`Access Denied`);
        return;
    }
    // Rest of your code that should only run when you have a user goes here.
})();
```

The only reason I'm wrapping the code above in an immediately invoked async function, is so I can use `await` instead of `then` to resolve that promise.

Comment: @Carpetfizz - This is the correct general structure.  There is NO need to wrap a function that already returns a promise in another promise.  `return value` is analogous to `resolve(value)` inside an `async` function and `throw err` is analogous to `reject(err)`.  There is actually no reason to need `async` and `await` here as one could just do `return axios(...).then(...).catch(...)` too.  `async/await` is a lot more useful when you are sequencing multiple async operations, not just making one.

Answer (score 1):

Functions marked with `async` are meant to be written using promise `.then()` callback style. That is, in order to resolve a value you use the `return` keyword and in order to reject a value you use the `throw` keyword. Thus your function should be written as follows:

```
async function getUser() {

    try {
        const userResponse = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: "some_url",
            data: "some string data",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        if (userResponse.data.status === 'success') {
            return validateResponse.data;
        } else {
            throw new Error(validateResponse.data);
            // Alternately you can also just:
            // throw validateResponse.data
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(validateResponse.data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Promise approach doesn't necessarily work either because when I use the Promise returned by getUser() and .catch() any errors, I won't know if the error came from the response from the server (the status was not 'success') or if the request itself failed.

I would look at rejecting the outer promise inside `getUser` in one of two examinable ways - and then call `getUser` using a promise topology that splits good data into a processing stream (chain of promises), and errors into another for differentiation. For example:

1. Create a data wrapper constructor called, say, GetUserData:

   ```
   const GetUserData = function( data) {
       this.data = data;
   }
   ```

   This may benefit from having another parameter for `getUser` argument values.
2. Remove the `try {` and `catch() {}` clauses. Let axios errors throw and reject the `getUser` promise.
3. Have `getUser` return the result of "success" or **throw** a `GetUserData` object:

   ```
   if (userResponse.data.status === 'success') {
       return  userResponse.data;
   }
   else {
       throw new GetUser( userResponse.data);
   }
   ```
4. Call `getUser` with a topology that differentiates the error types:

   ```
   let userPromise = getUser(); // parameterized?
   userPromise.then(data => { do something with user data}); // chain promises on "success" as needed

   // split errors into a .then handler for server errors and a .catch handler for axios errors:

   userPromise.catch( something => {
      if( something instanceOf GetUserData) {
          return something.data;
      }
      throw something; // rethrow axios error
   })
   .then ( data =>  { deal with unsuccessful server data})
   .catch( error => { deal with axios error })
   ```